# How do I add multiple files within the same commit, using a wildcard

Tags: git, wildcard, git-commit

I have 7 files that I want to commit to a remote repo, that start with the word 'Sanity....'

For example Sanity1, Sanity2, Sanity3, etc.

I want to be able to commit them all at once using a wild card string rather that try and commit them one by one.

Is this possible, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Sure, first add them using a wildcard (which will in fact be interpreted by the shell, not git), then commit.

```
git add Sanity*
git commit -m 'Sanity files added'
```

You can quote the wildcard to prevent shell from interpreting it, as git can do that, too:

```
git add 'Sanity*'
```

Comment: Weirdly, I do not recall ever needing to use quotes before, but today the wildcard did not work. Thanks! Quotes did the trick. Anyone know if this was a change in git, or what conditions necessitate its need?

Answer (score 2):

I played around with the answer from @choroba and found that you can work with multiple starting characters.

```
git add a* b*
```

will add all files beginning with `a` or `b`

Hope that's also helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

git commit Sanity* -m "commit Sanity files"